# how to edit legend\key in stata spmap?

Tags: legend, stata, choropleth

I am working on a map of counties in the US and the bank deposits for each county.
I am going to create a map for each year and I want the legend to be the same for each map so it will be easy to see the changes between the years.
I want to edit the legend such that it will show ranges I decide.

My code is:

```
shp2dta using cb_2021_us_county_500k, database("phdb") coordinates("phxy")genid(id) genc(c) replace
use phdb
generate fips = real(GEOID)
merge 1:1 fips using MapA2007
destring deposits, replace force

spmap deposits using "phxy", id(id) fcolor(Greens) ndfcolor(gs10)
```

I tried using:

```
spmap deposits using "phxy", id(id) fcolor(Greens) ndfcolor(gs10) 
  legend(title("Deposit Amounts") pos(8) region(lcolor(black))
   ring(0 "0-100000" 100000 "100001-250000" 250000 "250001-500000" 500000 "500001+"))
```

but it doesn't seem to make any difference and the legend is still as before.

chatgpt can't figure it out.

Comment: There is nothing reproducible here, but your use of `legend(ring())` seems to be confusing it with quite different  options.   That is a syntax for changing axis labels, which doesn't appear to be your problem at all. You may need to find a much simpler reproducible example.